# Math domain error from a negative number being generated

Tags: python, math

I am making a program to simulate a European call.

There is an error where I'm generating the sqrt of a log and it is giving me a negative number as the result. I know in Java it would cause no issue but in Python, it gives me a "Math domain error".

The error is being caused on this line.

```py
x = v1 * math.sqrt(-2.0 * math.log(s) / s) #The -2.0 doesnt work
```

Comment: What is your expected result when taking the sqrt of a negative number?  Are you expecting to go into the imaginary domain?

Comment: @user1558604 `x = -0.11998566239340747
x = -0.5801792658458768
x = 0.393404277646715
x = 1.17723372563267
x = 0.3560759915492943 `This is a sample output

Comment: Those values don't make any sense mathematically since you can't have a negative answer to a square root.

Comment: The calculation makes perfect sense when `0 < s <= 1`, in which case `math.log(s)` is negative (or zero) but `s` is positive. The problem is presumably that `s` has the wrong value, so the question will need to be edited to include the code providing the value of `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the square root of a negative number, so you expect to be working with complex numbers. You should import and use `cmath` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/cmath.html

```
import cmath
...
x = v1 * cmath.sqrt(-2.0 * math.log(s) / s)
```

Note that I didn't check the logic or function of your program, so whether the outcome actually makes sense is another matter.

Comment: Running your code seems to get it stuck in an infinite loop, printing the same values over and over, but the issue you're asking about is resolved.

Comment: Okay so cmath is what you would use to work with more extreme numbers. Thank you! And yes i just noticed im looking through my code right now to see what is wrong @Grismar

Comment: Happy to help, if you think this answers your question, please accept the answer with the check mark.

Comment: Depending on the value of `s` the expression in the `sqrt` function can be positive; e.g. when `s = 0.5`, `-2.0 * math.log(s) / s` is about 2.77. I think complex numbers are a red herring, and the problem is that `s` has the wrong value.

Comment: @kaya3 given the actual code that was there in a previous version of the question, I wouldn't be surprised if that turns out to be the case. However, in that version, s was the sum of two squares that would have a value in the range of [0.0..2.0], so at least half of the possible values would result in a non-negative log. Either way, the only "programming" problem here would be someone being unfamiliar with `cmath`, since the rest is just a matter of math, which is why I figured it needed pointing out :)

Comment: My best guess is that it should be `random.random()` for a double, and it should be scaled by a factor of a half, but that's just speculation. I haven't studied mathematical finance, but you're right, it does seem to be a matter of math rather than programming.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the code is working fine in Java (presumably using `Math.sqrt`), then we can rule out complex numbers. Java's standard library doesn't have a complex number datatype; you could use a third-party library class or write your own, but it's difficult to imagine you would have missed that out while trying to translate the code into Java. I conclude that the calculation is meant to have a real-numbered result.

For this to be true, it must be the case that 0 < s <= 1. This is because there is no real-valued square root or logarithm of a negative number, nor can you do log 0 or divide by 0. But for s <= 1, the function `math.log(s)` is negative, meaning `-2.0 * math.log(s)` is positive, and the calculation has a real-numbered value.

So the problem is presumably that `s` has the wrong value. I see from the edit history that the value of `s` is computed as follows:

```py
        v1 = 2.0 * random.randint(0,1) - 1.0
        v2 = 2.0 * random.randint(0,1) - 1.0
        s = v1*v1 + v2*v2
```

Here, `v1` and `v2` are each either -1 or 1, since `randint(0, 1)` generates either 0 or 1.
Either way, `v1*v1` and `v2*v2` are both 1, and hence `s` is 2.
This is not in the domain 0 < s <= 1, hence the error. This means there is a mathematical error in your code somewhere, and that's further evidenced by the fact that you're using random numbers in a way which guarantees the result is always 2.

So you need to go back to the textbook and/or the Java implementation to make sure `s` is being calculated and used correctly.